# I'm looking for some places where traditional Vedic Chanting books can be bought from

Tags: book-recommendation, vedic-chanting

I'm looking for a place where i can buy traditional Vedic chanting books like the one in the image below:

[image: enter image description here.]

Comment: Are u looking for Sanskrit books or transliterated books? DO u know about Vedic chanting?

Comment: Yes I can read and chant Sanskrit. I’m looking for the same type of traditional Sanskrit chanting books as the photo I attached

Comment: Chaukhambha and others. Which veda are you looking in particular? Which samhita ?

Comment: I would love to have the Gita in that particular  style of printing if available.

Comment: The attached image is not helpful unless you are looking for that particular size and shape

Answer (score 1):

Mantrapushpam published by Ramakrishna math has almost all important Veda mantras
This is the pocket version of it https://istore.chennaimath.org/product/mantrapushpam-sanskrit/

There is a larger one with bigger fonts also available